# Send variable from mongoose query to page without reload on click

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a link on my site. When clicked it'll call a function that does a  mongoose query. 
I'd like the results of that query to be sent to the same page in a variable without reloading the page. How do I do that? Right now it is just rendering the page again with new query result data.

```
// List comments for specified chapter id.
commentController.list = function (req, res) {
  var chapterId = req.params.chapterId;
  var query = { chapterId: chapterId };
  Chapter.find({ _id: chapterId }).then(function (chapter) {
    var chapter = chapter;
   Comment.find(query).then(function (data) {
  console.log(chapter);


    Chapter.find().then(function(chapters){
      return res.render({'chapterlinks', commentList: data, user: req.user, chapterq: chapter, chapters:chapters });

    })

});
```

})
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make that request from your browser via **AJAX**:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

This would be in the code for your client (browser), not the code for your server (nodejs).

**UPDATE:**

Here's a simple example, which uses **jQuery** to make things easier:

*(1) create a function that performs and handles the ajax request*

```
function getChapterLinks(chapterId) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/chapterLinks/"+chapterId,
    }).done(function(data) {
      //here you should do something with data
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

*(2) bind that function to a DOM element's click event*

```
$( "a#chapterLinks1" ).click(function() {
  getChapterLinks(1);
});
```

*(3) make sure that DOM element is somewhere in you html*

```
<a id="chapterLinks1">Get ChapterLinks 1</a>
```

Now when this `a#chapterLinks1` element is clicked, it will use **AJAX** to fetch the response of `/chaptersLink/1` from your server without reloading the page.

---

references:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.click/

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please form a proper, complete answer using what you have linked to, if necessary. Links go dead and your answer will be useless. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Perhaps I should have just simply answered "Use ajax", followed by a copy and pasted description of what it is, and omitted the link.

Comment: do i keep the res.render there? Where do i include the mongoose query in the ajax? calling that chapterlinks site is useless just gives me same data as before.

Comment: @user3542679 yeah keep it there. The mongoose query happens on the server when `/chaptersLink/1` is requested, while the ajax happens within the webpage browser to make that request without reload the page. Hope that helps

Comment: yup figured it out yesterday. forgot to vote the answer. thnx!

Comment: yup np! glad you got it